# PHP wrapping a section in square brackets

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = json_encode(
    array(
      'result'=>true, 
      'user'=> array('id'=>null, 'email'=>null, 'auth'=>false)

      )
   );
```

I have the above PHP and i am trying to wrap the `user` portion in square brackets.

Comment: `array( 'user' => ... )` maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

warp with one more `array()` of user portion

```
$arr = json_encode(
        array(
          'result'=>true, 
          'user'=>array(
                      array('id'=>null, 'email'=>null, 'auth'=>false)
                     )
          )
       );
```